# What is the html container or element on the mymsn pages?

Tags: javascript, html

If you log in to mymsn, you are able to customize the content and layout of your webpage. What I want to know is what kind of container are they using? Do they use an html element, or is it javascript or something else?

There are a bunch of boxes with a title, menu option, and minimize and delete buttons. Inside the boxes are unordered list links to topics of that particular subject.

Since I don't have 10 reputation I can't post an image of what it looks like.

Comment: Did you take a look at the page source?  Examine it in your browser's debugging/development tools?  What did you find?

Comment: JavaScript still uses HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code, you can see that this is just `HTML` elements like `div` used as containers for all the news dynamically added via JavaScript.

Check it by right clicking on any element in the page and select `inspect element`, you will see all the scripts running the page and handling interactions.